# alert with UIAlertController can't dissmiss it

Tags: swift

I'm creating an alert but I can't dismiss it when the user presses OK. I'm getting the following error:

> 2017-12-28 07:03:50.301947-0400 Prestamo[691:215874] API error:
>   <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x10249adc0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer =
>   > returned 0 width, assuming
>   UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

I was searching everywhere on the Internet but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   createAlert(title: "Licencia2", message: "En el momento no tienes una licencia válida!")
}

   func createAlert (title:String, message:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350784/how-to-present-an-alert-with-uialertcontroller?rq=1

Comment: It's not Duplicate. My alert sows, but I can't close it after.

Comment: IMO problem is in `viewDidAppear` which do not invoke `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`.

Comment: I added now the super.viewDidAppear(animated) and it didn't make any difference

Comment: Might be you have added alert twice.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47076989/1387438) looks like a similar problem and it is not alert related.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to dismiss alert controller. It will automatically dismiss after the action handler has been called. Just remove the dismiss line.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action) in

}))
self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still have the same error/it doesn't dismiss itself. I didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Please note the difference with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350952/1387438) and you code.
You didn't invoked `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` and this causes problems.

Below code (this is all I used) works for me without problems (I've test it):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        createAlert(title: "My test", message: "THis should work ok")
    }

    func createAlert (title:String, message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) {
            action in
            NSLog("it is working ok");
        })

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Xcode gives me a red error that presentViewController has been renamed to present. That is why I have present. The problems still remains